# Point Cloud Library (PCL) can't find PCLConfig.cmake or pcl-config.cmake [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, point-cloud-library

I've been trying to get the Point Cloud Library properly installed on my system. I would like to be able to get the basic [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config) working so that I know everything is correct and I can move on.

This has so far been a case of dealing with problem after problem of which this is the latest.

When I run `cmake` it errors and outputs:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" (requested
  version 1.3) with any of the following names:

    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/matt/hdd_home/pcl/tutorials/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I've installed PCL v1.8 from the Ubuntu [repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/pcl) but I've also installed `python-vtk` because it provides the package `libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets` which removes an error I was facing previously (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612973/point-cloud-library-pcl-basic-tutorial-cmake-and-make-errors-on-ubuntu-16-04)). Installation of `python-vtk` I  believe removes some of the packages bundled in `libpcl-dev` (PCL v1.8); I don't know whether this is relevant to the issue.

I'm not 100% sure that `PCLConfig.cmake` or `pcl-config.cmake` are even on my system. Maybe there has been an issue with the installation?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Super late to this but can you post the CMakeLists.txt you were using